# check as a root if a special path set

Tags: root, environment-variables

How do I check as a root if a special path set? This command

```
sudo echo $ANDROID_SDK_HOME
```

will show the path's value for a normal user and not for a root.

Comment: Try `sudo -i` before checking path set

Comment: @Mitch, exactly `sudo -i echo $ANDROID_SDK_HOME `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:

Open a terminal if necessary with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Step 2:

logon as root

```
sudo -i
```

Step 3:

Check the path

```
echo $ANDROID_SDK_HOME
```

Step 4:

If you opened a terminal at step one close it and you are no longer **root**; otherwise log out as root

```
exit
```